# How can i get the value of name from this list

Tags: python

```
data = [
    {
        'name': 'Instagram',
        'follower_count': 346,
        'description': 'Social media platform',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
        'follower_count': 215,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Portugal'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Ariana Grande',
        'follower_count': 183,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Dwayne Johnson',
        'follower_count': 181,
        'description': 'Actor and professional wrestler',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Selena Gomez',
        'follower_count': 174,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Kylie Jenner',
        'follower_count': 172,
        'description': 'Reality TV personality and businesswoman and Self-Made Billionaire',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Kim Kardashian',
        'follower_count': 167,
        'description': 'Reality TV personality and businesswoman',
        'country': 'United States'
    }]
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What did you expect would happen and what happened instead? Don't expect StackOverflow to write your code for you, but you can ask for help in improving code you wrote.

Comment: Post the code you have tried. And what confused you?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Teach me this language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Accessing a dict value is part of any tutorial or textbook chapter on the data type.  This is not a matter for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to get the value of name from each item in the list.

For example:

```
for item in data:
   print(item['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `list` of `dict`s.

If you want the name from the `n`th `dict` in the list, use `data[n]['name']` where n is the integer index of the list element. For example, for the first name, it would be `data[0]['name']`.

If you want all the names from all the `dict`s in the list, use `[d['name'] for d in data]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [ { 'name': 'Instagram', 'follower_count': 346, 'description': 'Social media platform', 'country': 'United States' }, { 'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo', 'follower_count': 215, 'description': 'Footballer', 'country': 'Portugal' }, { 'name': 'Ariana Grande', 'follower_count': 183, 'description': 'Musician and actress', 'country': 'United States' }, { 'name': 'Dwayne Johnson', 'follower_count': 181, 'description': 'Actor and professional wrestler', 'country': 'United States' }, { 'name': 'Selena Gomez', 'follower_count': 174, 'description': 'Musician and actress', 'country': 'United States' }, { 'name': 'Kylie Jenner', 'follower_count': 172, 'description': 'Reality TV personality and businesswoman and Self-Made Billionaire', 'country': 'United States' }, { 'name': 'Kim Kardashian', 'follower_count': 167, 'description': 'Reality TV personality and businesswoman', 'country': 'United States' }]

for dic in data:
    for key in dic:
        print(dic[key])
```

give your test condition inside the forloop